# RBAC not enabled in Strapi v4.11.1

Tags: strapi

I upgraded my Strapi installation from v4.6.0 to v.4.11.1 and can still see the "You have reached the limit" popup when trying to add a role in Strapi admin. Is there a DB migration script that is required to enable RBAC?